# P-Value of a Z-Score by Hand

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am running into an issue with a question that I am working on.  I want to find the $p$-value of a $z$-score by hand.  Here is the exact question and the work that I have done so far on it.:

> A controversy has arisen in the mathematics department at a large university over the proportion of freshman who had AP statistics in high school.  The department chair insists that exactly $70\%$ of freshman had AP statistics in HS, but the other department member suspect that the proportion may be different.  To resolve this issue, the department surveys $55$ freshman finding that $32$ had AP statistics in high school.  Using level $0.05$, test for evidence that the "other department members" are right.  Give the p-value.

The work that I have done so far is as follows:
$H_0$: $\pi=0.7$ vs HA: $\pi \ne 0.7$.

This is a two sided test.  $\hat\pi=32/55=.5818$ about.  $\alpha=0.05$

Working the formulas I obtain $z=-1.91$.  The rejection region is $|z|>1.96$.  We conclude that we fail to reject $H_0$ as $1.91 \ngtr 1.96$.

My issue now is figuring out how to find the $p$-value without using a calculator.  Any advise would be helpful.

Comment: I thought you meant without even a table.  You would have been super ultra doomed then.  that table is Hard to calculate by hand.

Comment: I would love to know how to do it without the table.  I think my issue here was that it had been way to long since I have seen this material.  I have always just relied on R or SAS to provide the answer.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html Welcome to erf.

Comment: I will check that out!  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think I answered this question myself after a little playing around.  Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

I simply found the value on the table that corresponded to my test statistic $-1.91$ and doubled it for the 2-sidedness.  This would give me the probability of having a score that is more extreme than what I actually obtained.  Therefore the p-value would be $2(0.0287)=0.0574$.  This would also confirm that we are unable to reject $H_0$.

Comment: You got it.  Note that if you get a test statistic that's positive, you'll want to use the negative version of it to get the probability; if you'd gotten $z=1.91$, you'd still want to use the table result for $z=-1.91$.

Comment: Yes defiantly.  It would be important to use the smaller one because the table provides the the probability up to that point.  Therefore to get the probability in the upper tale 1-alpha would provide that.  Thank's for the confirmation.  It's been some time since I had to go back and look at some of this earlier stuff.